# Get referenced sheet

Tags: excel

I want to get the value in a column next to a referenced cell

Example

**Sheet Products**

```
A1 = "test"
B1 = "next test"
B2 = "last test"
```

**Sheet Totals**
First i get the referenced cell in CEll A 1

```
A1 = =CELL("address";INDEX(Products!A:A;MATCH(C5;Products!A:A;0);0))
// returns Products$A$1
```

Now i want to get the value of B1,B2 and so on... based on what is in A1

I know with `Indirect(A1)` i will get the value of the referenced cell...but i have no clue how to get next to that one and so on....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OFFSET` function. The **OFFSET** function returns a cell or range of cells that is a specified number of rows and columns from a cell or range of cells.

For example, if `=INDIRECT(A1)` in **Sheet Totals** gives you **test** (which is `Cell A1` in **Sheet Products**) as result then to get value of `Cell B1` from **Sheet Products** you'll have to use `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(A1),0,1)` (same row, next column). Like wise, for `Cell B2` from **Sheet Products** you'll have to use `=OFFSET(INDIRECT(A1),1,1)` (next row, next coulmn).

For details on **OFFSET** function see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/OFFSET-function-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66).